# 'optional match" not returning null values within Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am writing a query to find out all the `directors` who have also `acted` in the `movie`.

I have written the following query to achieve that result:

```
optional match (director:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(movie:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(director)
return director.name, movie.title
```

The query is not returning the `null` values for the director name. My understanding is that  `"optional match" act as an "outer join"` and it should return null values as well.

Comment: Hi, this question is tagged as `graphql` and `facebook-graph-api` but it looks like your question is exclusively about Neo4j Cypher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are doing a query for entire path from person to movie to actors, thus optional match will return null if there is no such data exists. Lets say:

```
optional match (director:Person)-[:DIRECTS]->(movie:Movie)<-[:ACTS]-(director)
return director.name, movie.title

╒═══════════════╤═════════════╕
│"director.name"│"movie.title"│
╞═══════════════╪═════════════╡
│null           │null         │
└───────────────┴─────────────┘
```

When the documentation says optional match is an "outer join", it means that you should be doing this:

```
   match (director:Person)-[:DIRECTED]->(movie:Movie)
   optional match (movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(director)
   return director.name, movie.title
```

Ref: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/#optional-relationships